# How to open outlook mail object as a draft email before sending?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

```
void send_reply(Outlook.MailItem item, HashSet<string> names)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem eMail = item.Reply();
        // want to open an email draft box for user to type in the email's content then return to the program here
        eMail.Display();
        foreach (string s in names)
        {
            eMail.To = s;
            //MessageBox.Show("this is the guy we are sending to " + item.To);
            eMail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();

        }
    }
```

Want to send a reply to a given mailitem but only to the email addresses specified in names. Issue I'm having is when I call eMail.Display() it only shows for like half a second at most then the draft auto closes and I send a blank reply email to everyone in names.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I thisk that `Display()` does not wait the user to close the window and continues code execution suddenly. That's why it is closed and sent immediately...

Comment: @Seididieci Is there a way to pause execution until the user closes the window?

Comment: I've never worked with Outlook Interop bu you can investigate if there is an event raised on some user interaction (maybe Close or Send button) and move your logic there...

Comment: Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem seems you can get Send and Close Events so you can try to add "To" addresses there... And Undo things when the user simply "Close" the message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Display()` function returns immediately and makes your message to be sent empty.

You can wait by passing `true` to the function:

```cs
//...
  Outlook.MailItem eMail = item.Reply();
  eMail.Display(true); // <-- here
//...
```

This will make the window Modal and will wait for user to close it.

Maybe you have also to check if the user closed it without a text inside or have the intention to undo the operation...

To do this maybe you can check the message status or register a handler to one (or both) of `Close` (and `Send`) events.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you !